# Django 1.11.5 on Apache with mod_wsgi giving ImportError: No module named site

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi, importerror, updating

```
[Fri Sep 29 14:46:35.808072 2017] [wsgi:info] [pid 35637] mod_wsgi (pid=35697): Process 'swpdoc' has died, deregister and restart it.
[Fri Sep 29 14:46:35.808113 2017] [wsgi:info] [pid 35637] mod_wsgi (pid=35697): Process 'swpdoc' terminated by signal 1
[Fri Sep 29 14:46:35.808116 2017] [wsgi:info] [pid 35637] mod_wsgi (pid=35697): Process 'swpdoc' has been deregister`enter code here`ed and will no longer be monitored.
[Fri Sep 29 14:46:35.808944 2017] [wsgi:info] [pid 35699] mod_wsgi (pid=35699): Starting process 'swpdoc' with uid=48, gid=48 and threads=15.
[Fri Sep 29 14:46:35.809868 2017] [wsgi:info] [pid 35699] mod_wsgi (pid=35699): Python home /var/www/swpdoc/venswpdoc.
[Fri Sep 29 14:46:35.809895 2017] [wsgi:info] [pid 35699] mod_wsgi (pid=35699): Initializing Python.
ImportError: No module named site

WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/swpdoc/swpdocs/swpdoc/wsgi.py
<Directory /var/www/swpdoc/swpdocs/swpdoc>
 <Files wsgi.py>
      Require all granted
  </Files>
</Directory>
WSGIDaemonProcess swpdoc python-home=/var/www/swpdoc/venswpdoc  python-
path=/var/www/swpdoc/swpdocs
WSGIProcessGroup swpdoc
WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}

  [root@mrsblweb21548 modules]# ldd mod_wsgi.so
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffdd95fe000)
    libpython2.7.so.1.0 => /lib64/libpython2.7.so.1.0 (0x00007f1747989000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f174776d000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f1747568000)
    libutil.so.1 => /lib64/libutil.so.1 (0x00007f1747365000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007f1747063000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f1746ca0000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f1747f9d000)
```

If i use a project with django 1.9.5. it is working find and updating the django to newer version giving this error. Anyone help ?

Update:
     Changed permission on virtual environment directory and now getting 
        permission errors:
     [Fri Sep 29 19:12:35.371053 2017] [wsgi:warn] [pid 33023] (13)Permission 
         denied: mod_wsgi (pid=33023): Unable to stat Python home 
       /var/www/swpdoc/venswpdoc. Python interpreter may not be able to be 
           initialized correctly. Verify the supplied path and access 
            permissions for whole of the path.

Comment: Can you show us your VirtualHost file?

Comment: WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/swpdoc/swpdocs/swpdoc/wsgi.py
<Directory /var/www/swpdoc/swpdocs/swpdoc>
  <Files wsgi.py>
     Require all granted
  </Files>
</Directory>
WSGIDaemonProcess swpdoc python-home=/var/www/swpdoc/venswpdoc  python-path=/var/www/swpdoc/swpdocs
WSGIProcessGroup swpdoc
WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}

Comment: please update your question, instead of adding more comments.

Comment: But you don't say what version of Python you are expecting to use and which your Python virtual environment was created with. If you are expecting to use anything but Python 2.7 it will fail as mod_wsgi is compiled for Python 2.7. Alternatively ``/var/www/swpdoc/venswpdoc`` is not actually the root of the Python virtual environment, or maybe the Apache user doesn't have read access to it, although being under ``/var/www`` one would expect it did.

Comment: I am using Python 2.7.10 both virtual environment and mod_wsgi were build using Python 2.7.10. I have been figuring this out from yesterday but error still  exists.

Comment: Can you give a example what permission I have to set. <br/> /var/www/swpdoc/venswpdoc is actually the root of the Python virtual environment. I had mod_wsgi with same setup working before with django 1.9.5. I updated the django and now it is giving me this error.

Comment: What do the following give you in command line interpreter for both system Python version and when run Python from your virtual environment. ``sys.prefix``, ``sys.version`` and ``sys.real_prefix``. This is after importing ``sys`` obviously. The last one should fail on system Python but work on virtual environment.

Comment: You can also comment out existing daemon process configuration and ``WSGIScriptAlias`` and replace with ``WSGIScriptAlias`` which points to a test script containing what is described in http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/checking-your-installation.html#python-installation-in-use

Comment: **Here is the output from system python**
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> sys.prefix
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'sys' is not defined
>>> import sys
>>> sys.prefix
'/usr'
>>> sys.version
'2.7.5 (default, Nov 20 2015, 02:00:19) \n[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-4)]'
>>> sys.real_prefix
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'real_prefix'

Comment: **Output from virtual environment**
[root@mrsblweb21548 swpdoc]# /var/www/swpdoc/venswpdoc/bin/python
Python 2.7.10 (default, Apr  5 2016, 11:47:06)
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-4)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> sys.prefix
'/var/www/swpdoc/venswpdoc'
>>> sys.version
'2.7.10 (default, Apr  5 2016, 11:47:06) \n[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-4)]'
>>> sys.real_prefix
'/usr/local'
>>>

Comment: **I have one second python installed which I am using for virtual environment**
[root@mrsblweb21548 swpdoc]# python27
Python 2.7.10 (default, Apr  5 2016, 11:47:06)
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-4)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> sys.prefix
'/usr/local'
IndentationError: unexpected indent
>>> sys.version
'2.7.10 (default, Apr  5 2016, 11:47:06) \n[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-4)]'
>>> sys.real_prefix
Traceback (most recent call last):

Comment: **Here is the output from the test command**
sys.version = '2.7.5 (default, Nov 20 2015, 02:00:19) \n[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-4)]'
sys.prefix = '/usr'

Comment: When i build mod_wsgi i did configure it with ./configure  --with-python=/usr/local/bin/python Not sure why it is using system python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually caused by you trying to make mod_wsgi use a Python virtual environment for a different version of Python than mod_wsgi was compiled for.

Check what version of Python mod_wsgi is compiled for.

- http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/checking-your-installation.html#python-shared-library

Indicate what version of Python your virtual environment was created against.

Comment: They both are using the same version. I had a similar setup before for django 1.9.5. Not not what happened with the update.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, you only need to add the root application path to the "python-path", then it can recognize all apps in your project (I assume that "site" is an app in your project). So, you need to replace this line in your config file:

```
WSGIDaemonProcess swpdoc python-path=/var/www/swpdoc
```

If you are using a virtualenv, you can add the virtualenv packages with this line:

```
WSGIDaemonProcess swpdoc python-path=/var/www/swpdoc:/var/www/swpdoc/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages
```

You just need to replace the version of the python installed in your virtualenv.

Additionally, every time you update Django, you need to take a look at the release notes https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/releases/1.11/

Comment: You should not use ``python-path`` to refer to ``site-packages``, that is not the preferred way. Read http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/virtual-environments.html for how to set up Python virtual environments with mod_wsgi correctly.

Comment: Also, the ``site`` module is not part of any application code. It is a special module which is part of the Python installation. Failure to import it indicates mod_wsgi can't find the Python installation.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but it still did not work.Same error. I had mod_wsgi with same setup working before with django 1.9.5. I updated the django and now it is giving me this error.